# replace Html by tag in android

Tags: java, android

```
<img src="images/DM_LOGO_HEADER.png" alt="DailyMed Logo Header image" />
```

i want to replace src="images/DM_LOGO_HEADER.png" with my own Text in android html prasing

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
final String html = "<img src=\"images/DM_LOGO_HEADER.png\" alt=\"DailyMed Logo Header image\" />";
final String newHtml = html.replace("src=\"images/DM_LOGO_HEADER.png\"", "Your own text");
```